# Tomcat 8: how to NOT precompile JSP?

Tags: jsp, tomcat8, precompile

The manual says that to NOT precompile I should set (development=false), like this extract from web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>development</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

My problem is that I'm still having Tomcat 8 precompile JSP files, overwriting newer files.  For example:

Login_jsp.class has date 4/5/17 and time 8:30:04

Login.jsp has date 4/5/17 and time 8:29:22

The regenerated Login_jsp.java and Login_jsp.class both have date 4/5/17 and time 8:29:22

What else must I do to have Tomcat 8 respect the existing precompiled JSP files?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set checkInterval? If yes, background compiles may work.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Configuration

checkInterval - If development is false and checkInterval is greater than zero, background compiles are enabled. checkInterval is the time in seconds between checks to see if a JSP page (and its dependent files) needs to be recompiled. Default 0 seconds.

Comment: We tried the combo of (development=false, checkInterval=0).  No effect. Note that the upon-access recompiling of JSP replaces the existing compiled .class file.

Comment: Did you ever found out how you can prevent it ?

Comment: You can't prevent it. Tomcat uses file timestamp to keep compiled jsp files in sync with the source. No match = recompile, that's all there is to it. It has nothing to do with modification checks, it happens on first access after server startup.